# Euler-Maclaurin formula for half integer values in summation

Tags: integration

I am trying to use the Euler-Maclaurin formula to approximate a sum with the form $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n+1/2)$$ where the argument is a half integer. Can anyone help me adjust the formula for such a case?

Thanks

Comment: The formula needs no adjusting, just apply it to $g(n)=f(n+1/2)$.